# Saving FK model field by fieldname_id allows non-existing FK relations

Tags: python, django

I have a model consisting of two ForeignKey fields as below.  (This is a ManytoMany `through` field)

```
class EntityConceptLink(models.Model):
    entity = models.ForeignKey(Entity)
    standard_concept = models.ForeignKey(StandardConcept)
    other fields...
```

I am trying to create objects like so:

```
EntityConceptLink.objects.get_or_create(
    entity_id=entity_id,  # passing in an integer, should be PK of Entity
    standard_concept=concept)  # passing in a model instance
```

The problem is, when I pass in an entity_id corresponding to an *nonexistent Entity*, the above code somehow nonetheless saves the model instance.  It's only later when I try to do `entityconceptlinkinstance.entity` that a `DoesNotExist: Entity matching query does not exist` is raised.

Shouldn't the model fail validation during the attempt to save?  Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I think below code should work fine.

```
EntityConceptLink.objects.get_or_create(
    entity__id=entity_id,  # Believe `id` would be the primary key
    standard_concept=concept)
```

In the above case it will raise error if entity model do not find the required id. See the use double `__` instead of single `_` in the entity id.

Comment: That does not work.  Raises `IntegrityError: appname_entityconceptlink.entity_id may not be NULL` whether I use a valid entity id or not

Comment: also running `EntityConceptLink.objects.create(...)` with those kwargs fails with `TypeError: 'entity__id' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`